# Is it true that for any positive integer $n$, there exists an integer $x$ where there are at least $n$ primes between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$

Tags: divergent-series, square-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Am I correct that this follows directly from two observations:

(1)  The sum of the reciprocals of primes [diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes).

(2)  The sum of the reciprocals of squares [converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)

Here's my thinking:

> If there existed an integer $m$ that was a maximum number of primes between two consecutive squares, then the sum of the reciprocal of primes would be less than $m\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ which would be convergent which is not the case.

Am I correctly understanding the implication of these two observations? Are there other well known properties that stem from these two observations?

Comment: A couple of question. First, _which_ squares? Any of them? Secondly: did you mean to write "the sum of **reciprocals of the primes** would be less than $m\frac{\pi^2}{6}$"? Because if we stick with your statement of summing just **the primes**, then naturally it's going to be greater than $m\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: Sorry.  I meant the solution of the Basel problem (which I linked to).  So, the sum of squares is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}$  Yes, I meant the sum of the reciprocal of the primes.  I will update my question.  Thanks!

Comment: Larry, the number of primes up to large $N,$   divided by $\sqrt N,$  increases without bound  as it is essentially $\frac{\sqrt N}{\log N}.$  If a square  is a pigeonhole that gets the primes between it and the next square, the pigeonhole with the most primes has, well, many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is mostly correct. Two slight imprecisions:

- Where it says “sum of the primes” it should say “sum of the reciprocals of the primes”, as above.
- It doesn’t make much sense to say “the sum would be less than $m\frac{\pi^2}6$ which would be convergent”, since $m\frac{\pi^2}6$ is a constant. The argument should be that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes would be [dominated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) by the sum of the $m$-fold reciprocals of the squares, and would thus converge; its value would then be less than $m\frac{\pi^2}6$.

There’s no shortage of well-known properties that stem from $(1)$, but I’m not aware of any that stem from the combination of $(1)$ and $(2)$.